# Unity Vector Raycast Debug

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to draw my raycast to screen in 2D

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 2f, layerMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+250, transform.position.z)), Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+250, transform.position.z)), Color.magenta);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(hit.normal.x, hit.normal.y, -10)), Color.magenta);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(hit.normal.x, hit.normal.y, 10)), Color.magenta);
```

The ray cast is working, but i would like to see it.  Currently I see nothing. I would have thought I needed simply the original 3D vector transform + a displacement from it. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving it a duration, I'm pretty sure that `Debug.DrawRay` **persists only one frame**. So either try giving it a duration:

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+250, transform.position.z)), Color.green, 2.0f);
```

Or draw it inside Update or preferably OnDrawGizmos:

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, (transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 250, transform.position.z)), Color.green);
}
```

The above code rendered a green line that was visible every frame. Basically what you'd expect it to do.

It doesn't *have* to be in OnDrawGizmos by any means, but doing it with the OnDrawGizmos has the advantage of neatly separating your debug code from other code, so I tend to go with that solution.